# Send Email with apache commons

Tags: java, apache, email

Here is my code to send a `MultiPartEmail` with attachment in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create The Attachment
    EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath("check.png");
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    attachment.setDescription("My file on my system");
    attachment.setName("Check icon");

    // Create The Email
    MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
    try {
        email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
        email.setAuthentication("MyUsername", "Mypassword");
        email.setFrom("Myemail@gmail.com");
        email.addTo("myfriend@gmail.com");
        email.setMsg("Body Of Message");
        email.attach(attachment);
        email.send();

    } catch (EmailException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But, this exception occur:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:25
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
at networking.EmailWithAttachment.main(EmailWithAttachment.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a4sm18234039eep.12 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2133)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1630)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1132)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
... 7 more
```

Comment: `530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.` <-- this is what you need to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google e-mail servers refuse to talk to you in plain text. You need to turn on SSL with

```
email.setTLS(true);
```

See:  [Sending email in Java using Apache Commons email libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848794/sending-email-in-java-using-apache-commons-email-libs)

Comment: It works with `email.setTLS(true);` , But IDE warning that this method `Deprecated` .